# Why stop() makes animation repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if I bother you with this silly question. I am a newbie with programming/ jQuery and I have a problem using stop()on the element with more than one animation method and a callback function.

Please refer what I've done here: http://cdpn.io/sBbJw

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({height:'300px',opacity:'0.8'}, 2000);
    $("div").animate({width:'300px',opacity:'0.6'}, 2000);
    $("div").animate({height:'100px',opacity:'0.4'},2000);
    $("div").animate({width:'100px',opacity:'0.2'},2000, function() {
        alert("Have a nice day !");
     });
  });
 $("#done").click( function() {
   $("div").stop();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button>Start Animation</button>
<button id="done">Stop Animation</button>
<br/><br/>
<div></div>
```

Stop() makes the animation and callback function repeat 2 times, when you just click "Stop" button once. Do I make something wrong?

Comment: Well, you are binding the first event handler to **both** button elements. I.e. when you click the `#done` button, the both event handlers are executed. So, the problem is not `.stop`, it's how you bind the handlers.

Comment: It's just because you assigned 2 click events, one for each button element and the second to the button with id #done.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/QVt6L/1/

```
 $("button").click(function(){ means on click of every button
```

give id like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Start").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({height:'300px',opacity:'0.8'}, 2000);
    $("div").animate({width:'300px',opacity:'0.6'}, 2000);
    $("div").animate({height:'100px',opacity:'0.4'},2000);
    $("div").animate({width:'100px',opacity:'0.2'},2000, function() {
        alert("Have a nice day !");
     });
  });
 $("#done").click( function() {
   $("div").stop(true);
  });
});

<button id="Start">Start Animation</button>
<button id="done">Stop Animation</button>
<br/><br/>
<div style="background-color:red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I check your code and make a little change

1 ) `Give the ID of Animated Div`

In this case you must have to set the ID to animated DIV because animation occurs
more then once and when you clicked on stop() then it trigger the animation and wait for complete it,after completion you assign callback to alert(),so when ever you press start it set alert for click and as well callback.

[See Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/aVn7E/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to be more constructive and added true as param to stop

```
<SCRIPT Language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   $("div").animate({height:'300px',opacity:'0.8'}, 2000, function(){
    $("div").animate({width:'300px',opacity:'0.6'}, 2000, function(){
        $("div").animate({height:'100px',opacity:'0.4'},2000, function(){
            $("div").animate({width:'100px',opacity:'0.2'},2000, function() {
                alert("Have a nice day !");
             });
        });
    });
  });
 });

 $("#done").click( function() {
  $("div").stop( true )
 });
});
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: to understand more in depth about parameter which i mentioned inside stop read about "clearQueue" under this link http://api.jquery.com/stop/